# Chapter numbering dissapears with picture in heading

Tags: graphics, sectioning, numbering, chapters

This is the chapter heading style I'm working on (note: this image was done in photoshop, as a guide. Also, the black box represents a picture).

[image]

The LaTex code I currently have gets me pretty close, but for some reason I can't get "chapter 1" to appear!

Why not?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\fontsize{30}{70}\selectfont}
%{\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\Huge\thechapter}
{}
{1ex}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
    (0pt,-115pt)$) {\includegraphics[width=7cm]{tunga}};
    \vspace{100pt}\filcenter #1
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, you commented out the part that prints “Chapter 1”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commented out the part that should print “Chapter 1”.

Maybe this is nearer to what you have in mind.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,twocolumn]{book}
%\special{papersize=210mm,297mm} % <--- what for?
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
%\usepackage{fix-cm} % <--- what for?
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\filcenter\fontsize{30}{42}\selectfont}
  {\Large\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {12pt}
  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
    (0pt,-115pt)$) {\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=2cm]{example-image}};}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{4cm}{40pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And thank you for the extra notes, inside the code.